# Python - Unable to detect face and eye?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, face-detection, eye-detection

I am trying to create a face and eye detection using OpenCV library. This is the code I been working with. It's running smoothly with no errors but the only problem is not showing any results no faces and eyes are found with this code

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
import os

# Get user supplied values
imagePath = sys.argv[1]


# Create the haar cascade
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\Users\Karthik\Downloads\Programs\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascad_frontalface_default.xml')
eyeCascade= cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\Users\Karthik\Downloads\Programs\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_eye.xml')

# Read the image
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect faces in the image
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.2,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
)

print "Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces))

# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    eyes = eyeCascade.detectMultiscale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0, 255, 0), 2)


cv2.imshow("Faces found", image)
print image.shape
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it works in my jupyter notebook on Ubuntu 15.10 using OpenCV 3.1.0-dev with python 3.4

Could it be, that you have a simple typo?

`haarcascad_frontalface_default.xml`  => `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`

and here:

`eyes = eyeCascade.detectMultiscale(roi_gray)`
=> `eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)`

That's my working code:

```py
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
import os

# Create the haar cascade
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eyeCascade= cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

# Read the image
image = cv2.imread('lena.png', 0)

if image is None:
    raise ValueError('Image not found')

# Detect faces in the image
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(image)

print('Found {} faces!'.format(len(faces)))

# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), 255, 2)
    roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    eyes = eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(roi)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh), 255, 2)


plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot its working perfectly fine for me when i run this code through cmd its showing results but when i run the program through IDLE its showing an  error of [Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Acads\7.1 Sem\BTP\FaceDetect-master\3.py", line 19, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor] 
 after this error i removed [ gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) ] now its working with no errors 
can you help me with this too

Comment: If you now have a 0 flag in your `cv2.imread(file, 0)` you will already read the input image as grayscaled so your image has only 1 channel (scn). Thats why cvtColor says "No I cannot convert a 3 channel BGR image to 1 channel gray because it is already 1 channel and i need `scn == 3 or scn == 4`". So remove the 0 from imread if you want both color and grayscaled image in your code.

Comment: For future errors like this use `print(image.shape)` that will give you (height, width, channels) of you image. If it only returns a tuple with (height, width) than your image is grayscaled.

Comment: Thanks again and just one more doubt 
  faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(image)  
here you didn't specify any scale factor those things so what does it take from image

Comment: As you can read in the docs http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#aaf8181cb63968136476ec4204ffca498 the scaleFactor is 1.1 if you don't specify anything (optional argument). In the most cases when I use the cascade classifier for face detection I don't use the optional args and it's always fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help can you please suggest me some nice materials for learning image processing using python mainly eye and pupil detection

Comment: I'm sorry for my use cases haar-like feature based classifier was always sufficient, so I do not have experience with other eye detection methods. But this would maybe a great new standalone stackoverflow question/discussion.